# Are single loops or dense loops more computationlly efficent in matlab?

Tags: matlab, memory, for-loop, vectorization

Im am currently writing a code to implement a numerical approximation to the 3D steady state heat equation using finite difference matrix methods. This involves discritising the 2nd order PDE into the matrix A and solving Ax=b. where x is temperature at each of the specified grid points. Further information on this type of question can be found here:

http://people.nas.nasa.gov/~pulliam/Classes/New_notes/Matrix_ODE.pdf

To complete this problem, I have represented the 3D matrix A by a 2D array calling the values in the 1D array b using an indexing function of the form:

```
i+(j-1)*Nx+Nx*Ny*(k-1)
```

for the (i,j,k)th element of the 3D matrix where Nx, Ny, Nz are the number of points in the x,y,z coordinates. There ends up being a lot of loop computation in order to create the matrix A and b and I was wondering what is the most computationally efficient and less memory exhaustive way to run these loops, i.e. is it better to use something like

```
for j=1:Ny
    for i=2:Nx-1
        b(i+(j-1)*Nx)=D4;    
    end
end


for j=1:Ny
    for i=2:Nx-1
        b(i+(j-1)*Nx+Nx*Ny*(Nz-1))=D3;   
    end
end
```

or should I condense these into a single loop like:

```
for j=1:Ny
    for i=2:Nx-1
        b(i+(j-1)*Nx)=D4;
        b(i+(j-1)*Nx+Nx*Ny*(Nz-1))=D3;    
    end
end
```

I have preallocated both the arrays A and b. Is there a vectorised way to do this also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method should be slightly faster since it performs the same number of calculations with fewer increments of the loop variables. You can look into MATLAB's built-in stopwatch commands `tic` and `toc` to time your code. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html

Something more vectorized might be possible but I would need to know more about the format of the arrays that contain `D3` and `D4`. The `reshape()` function might be able to help.

Comment: D3 and D4 are just constants this formula is for part of the boundary conditions. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Nx`, `Ny`, `Nz`, `D3` and `D4` to be scalars and that you are using pre-allocation for `b` with zeros, you may try this vectorized approach -

```
I = 2:Nx-1; %// Vectors to represent i
J = 1:Ny; %// Vectors to represent j

ind1 = bsxfun(@plus,I,[(J-1)*Nx]'); %//' Indices, 1st set of nested loops
ind2 = bsxfun(@plus,I,[(J-1)*Nx+Nx*Ny*(Nz-1)]'); %//' Indices, 2nd set of loops

b(ind1) = D4; %// Assign values for 1st set
b(ind2) = D3; %// Assign values for 2nd set
```